# Requirejs and Karma: cannot detect the source file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, requirejs, karma-runner

I am trying to test my angular scripts using Karma and requirejs, but I keep getting this error

> Firefox 28.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.9) ERROR: 'There is no timestamp for /base/app/public/js/test/unit/controllersSpec.js!'
>
> WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/app/public/js/test/unit/controllersSpec.js
>
> Firefox 28.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.9) ERROR
>     Error: Script error for: test/unit/controllersSpec
>     http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>     at /Users/Masanori/Desktop/FlippySurvey/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:166

I tried changing the baseUrl in different ways but I still keep receiving the error.
Can somebody help me figure out this problem? I'll appreciate for your help!

My directory structure is like this

```
app/
   public/
       vendors/
            ....
       js/
          controllers.js
          controllers/
                   mainctrl.js
test
   unit
        controllersSpec.js
   karma.conf.js
   test-main.js
```

Here are my test-main.js and karma.conf.js

```
test-main.js'

var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;

var pathToModule = function(path) {
  return path.replace(/^\/base\//, '').replace(/\.js$/, '');
};

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
  if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
    // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
    allTestFiles.push(pathToModule(file));
  }
});

require.config({
  paths:{
    'angular'     : '/base/app/public/vendors/angular/angular',
    'angularMocks': '/base/app/public/vendors/angular-mock/angular-mock',
    'domReady'    : '/base/app/public/vendors/requirejs-domready/domready',
    'angularRoute': '/base/app/public/vendors/angular-route/angular-route'
  },

  baseUrl: '/base/app/public/js',

  shim: {
    'angular' :{'exports':'angular'},
    'angularRoute' :['angular'],
    'angularMocks':{
      deps: ['angular'],
      'exports':'angular.mock'
    }
  },

  deps: allTestFiles,

  callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
     config.set({

    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],

    files: [
      {pattern: 'unit/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'unit/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: '../app/public/js/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: '../app/public/js/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: '../app/public/vendors/**/*.js', included: false},
      'test-main.js'
    ],

    exclude: [

    ],

    preprocessors: {

    },

    reporters: ['progress'],

    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch: true,

    browsers: ['Firefox'],

    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay.

I just had to get rid of some code, which Karma automatically inserts when you do karma init with requirejs.

---

In test-main.js

```
var pathToModule = function(path) {
  return path.replace(/^\/base\//, '').replace(/\.js$/, '');
};
Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
   if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
   // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
    allTestFiles.push(pathToModule(file));
   }
});
```

Remove pathToModule

```
Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
   if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
      allTestFiles.push(file);
    }
});
```

Now karma reads all the test files!